# Beautiful Soup 4 not printing text from a webpage

Tags: python, networking, encoding

I'm using python 3.4 with Beautiful Soup 4 and requests.
I am trying to grab the webpage, and print the text from it using beautiful soup. It can grab the webpage and print the title, It can even prettify if I provide it with the encoding, which is utf-8, but when I try to print the text from the page, it goofs over an encoding error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

sparknotesSearch = requests.get("http://www.sparknotes.com/search?q=Sonnet")
soup = BeautifulSoup(sparknotesSearch.text)

print (soup.title)
#Can't print this?
print(soup.get_text())
```

The error/output I get is this:

```
<title>SparkNotes Search Results: sONNET</title>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cayle J. Elsey\Dropbox\Programming\Salient_Point\networking.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(soup.get_text())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2192' in position 6238: character maps to <undefined>
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

Comment: That solved, the error, don't know how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just encode your string into UTF-8 . and Your problem will be solved

```
 html= soup.prettify()
   html=html.encode('UTF-8')
```